# Calculating mode in Pandas when using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table as follows:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
AAA  | 1    | a
AAA  | 1    | a
AAA  | 1    | b
AAA  | 2    | b
AAA  | 2    | b
AAA  | 2    | b
AAA  | 3    | a
BBB  | 1    | b
BBB  | 1    | b
```

I want to reduce the table in the following two steps:

1. Find the most frequently occurring value in Col3 corresponding to the (Col1, Col2) value pair.
2. From the result of step1, keep only the most frequently occurring value corresponding to Col1 value.

Applying step1 to the table above:
The mode (or most frequently occurring value) corresponding to `(AAA, 1)` is `a`, and so on. We get:

```
Col1 | Col2 | newCol1
AAA  | 1    | a
AAA  | 2    | b
AAA  | 3    | a
BBB  | 1    | b
```

Applying step2 to this table, we see that `a` is the mode corresponding to `AAA` and `b` is the most frequently occurring value corresponding to `BBB` - so we get:

```
Col1 | newCol2
AAA  | a  
BBB  | b
```

Comment: the second groupby is on just column1 right?

Comment: What if the mode isn't unique?

Comment: @coldspeed I forgot to mention the heuristic for this edge case in my question: I'm just going to select the mode at index 0 in this case.

Comment: @anky_91 yes, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do it one line

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2']).Col3.apply(pd.Series.mode).\ 
      groupby(level=0).apply(pd.Series.mode)
Out[136]: 
Col1   
AAA   0    a
BBB   0    b
Name: Col3, dtype: object
```

---

Just for fun

```
pd.crosstab([df.Col1,df.Col2],df.Col3).idxmax(1).groupby(level=0).apply(pd.Series.mode)
Out[140]: 
Col1   
AAA   0    a
BBB   0    b
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

So you mean:

```
df_new=df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].apply(lambda x:x.mode()).reset_index([0,1]).\
groupby('Col1')['Col3'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()).reset_index(0).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_new)

  Col1   Col3
0  AAA      a
1  BBB      b
```

Comment: You may want to do with groupby with level